# Is it possible Magento 2 site work without ssh/command prompt?

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, magento2.3.1, command-line, ssh

I am installed Magento 231 site. After that, I want to installed Magento extension and theme but I have no ssh or command prompt?

Someone help me how can I achieve this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: refer this link if that's relevant to you **https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/108717/magento2-without-ssh**

Answer (score 1):

Create command.php file on root.
Add following code and then run
But make sure put bin path 
Try this

```
   <?php

    echo nl2br(shell_exec('php /home/public_html/bin/magento cache:clean 2>&1;'));

    //echo nl2br(shell_exec('php /home/public_html/bin/magento cache:flush 2>&1;'));

    //echo nl2br(shell_exec('php /home/public_html/bin/magento setup:upgrade 2>&1;'));

    //echo nl2br(shell_exec('php /home/public_html/bin/magento setup:di:compile 2>&1;'));

    //echo nl2br(shell_exec('php /home/public_html/bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy 2>&1;'));

    //echo nl2br(shell_exec('php /home/public_html/bin/magento cache:flush 2>&1;'));

    echo nl2br(shell_exec('php -v')); 

    echo "executed";

    ?>
```